# Xively string data

Tags: string, xively

I would like to know if it is possible to send a block of data like 128 bytes of data to a Xively server MOTOROLA SREC for example I need this to do firmware upgrades / download images to my Arduino connected device? As far as I can see one can only get - datapoints / values ?

Comment: Not sure why someone downvoted this question at the beginning actually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A value of a datapoint can be a string. Firmware updates can be implement using Xively API V2 by just storing string encoded binaries as datapoints, provided that the size is small.

You probably can make some use of timestamps for rolling back versions that did work or something similar. Also you probably want to use the datapoints endpoint so you can just grab the entire response body and no need to parse anything.

`/v2/feeds/<feed_id>/datastreams/<datastream_id>/datapoints/<timestamp>.csv`

I suppose, you will need implement this in the bootloader which needs to be very small and maybe you can actually skip paring the HTTP headers and only attempt to very whether the body looks right (i.e. has some magic byte that you put in there, you can also try some to checksum it. This would a little bit opportunistic, but might be okay for an experiment. You should probably add Xively device provisioning to this also, but wouldn't try implementing everything right away.

It is however quite challenging to implement reliable firmware updates and there are sever papers out there which you should read. Some suggest to make device's behaviour most primitive you can, avoid any logic and make it rely on what server tells it to do.

To actually store the firmware string you can use [cURL helper](https://xively.com/curl).

### *Add first version into a new datastream*

[image]

### *Update with a new version*

[image]

Comment: I can get links to some of the papers I refer to if anyone needs it.

Comment: Don't forget to tweet @XivelyLabs or blog about any progress or contact Xively support!